# How to find out whether a URL is up and running?

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

I have four URLs and I was trying to build a simple HTML-JavaDcript way of finding out whether the URLs are up and running.

The URLs are like this:

- `https://www.kbhome1.com`
- `https://www.kbhome2.com`
- `https://www.kbhome3.com`
- `https://www.kbhome4.com`

Now when the URLs are loaded using the address bar in IE, they all provide a common text which has some variations with respect to the URL used like this:

- `Your app1 is up and running`
- `Your app2 is up and running`
- `Your app3 is up and running`
- `Your app4 is up and running`

So I was trying to get the URLs loaded in iframe and then I was trying to get the common text `Your app`, which will let me know that the individual URLs are up. Now the problem is the URLs are hosted in different servers and as such due to `Same Origin Policy violation`, I keep getting this error:

> iframe error permission denied to access property

Now does anybody know any other way to achieve what I am trying to do? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

1. It sounds like you have iframes open with those URLs loaded in them. You can send the iframe windows a message via `postMessage` (which is allowed cross-origin) and have them reply saying whether they're up. E.g., in your main window:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
       // Check iframe reply's origin and handle it here
   }, false);

   theIframe.contentWindow.postMessage("ack", "https://kbhome1.com");
   ```

   There, you're listening for a message back, and sending a message to the iframe asking it to reply.

   More on `postMessage`:

   - [In the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/)
   - [On MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
   - [Article on using it cross-origin](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)
2. But it doesn't need to be that complicated. If all you want to do is make sure those apps are up, put a small script file on each of them, e.g. `https://kbhome1.com/up.js`, with this in it:

   ```
   hostStatus("kbhome1", true);
   ```

   ...and then on your page, include a function:

   ```
   function hostStatus(host, up) {
       // ...mark that host as "up" or "down" based on the `up` flag
   }
   ```

   ...and include a script tag for each host:

   ```
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = "https://kbhome1.com/up.js";
   script.onerror = function() {
       hostStatus("kbhome1", false); // It's not up
   };
   document.querySelector("script").parentNode.appendChild(script);
   ```

   If you see the `hostIsUp` call, it's up; if you don't, it isn't (and we can use the `error` event, above, to get a positive "it's not up" result).

   You can do that more than once if you're doing an ongoing "live" status page.

Comment: Thanks , this looks like  a very good idea . Let me check whether this works out for me .

Comment: So, the problem with both the options are that they depend on me having control over the urls . Unfortunately the urls are hosted in a server to which I have no access . When i tried out the first option, I realized that the `receiveMessage()` function must be on the app from the hosted url. But that's not possible in my case, since I do not have permission to change anything in that app and from my side of the code I can't anyways access anything inside the web page depicted via the urls . Hence , none of these options actually work out for me .

Comment: But I was not aware of the `postmessage()`  functionality . That was a good read though . If you can think of any other ways of doing it , please let me know .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: If you can't control the content of the sites you're trying to look at, I don't think there's a purely client-side solution. You'll have to have a server somewhere that you query, which can in turn query the hosts you're testing (since server-side code won't run up against the Same Origin Policy).

Comment: Yes, you are quite right . However, what I was thinking now is that : Since I cannot access anything inside the iframe ; what if I pro grammatically take a snap shot of the iframe content and extract the text `Your app` from it. If I am able to extract the text, then that will mean that the site is up . Just a thought , dunno about the complexity of this though .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: But to access the text, you'd have to get around the SOP, which is there specifically to *prevent* you accessing the text. :-)

Comment: Will it be so ? Because, I will be taking the snapshot(using html2canvas probably) and keep it my HDD and read the text from that image . Do you reckon I will face the SOP violation problem there  ?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: Your HDD? What? I thought you were looking for a client-side solution. If you can involve a server, there's no need for anything that complex at all.

Comment: Yes, I think that will be the best way to go  instead of making it very complicated . Thanks for the assist .

Answer (score 0):

You might try to send  simple *AJAX GET* request to each of these URLs and see if you get a **200** status back.

Again, this might fails for cross domain issues you might try with ***jsonp*** datatype.

Comment: Do you have any sample examples of doing this using jsonp ?